# Two almost exactly the same programs but different output

Tags: c, algorithm, gcc

Hi I have made a very simple program that should work but it don't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int usedNumbers[256];
    memset(usedNumbers,0,256);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<256; ++i){
        while(1){
            int r = rand()%256;
            if( !usedNumbers[r] ){
                usedNumbers[r] = 1;
                break;
            }
            printf("Test: %03d -> %03d\n", i, r);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The idea of the program is to print numbers from 0 to 255 on the screen in the random order but the program stops on 84th number on 32 computers and 144th number on 64 bit computers. If i only move the "int usedNumbers[256];" above the function like that:

```
#include <string.h>

int usedNumbers[256];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

Program works as it supposed to.
Why is it that?
I am using the newest GNU/GCC compiler and C11 standard.

Comment: `memset(usedNumbers,0,256);` should be `memset(usedNumbers,0, sizeof(usedNumbers));`

Comment: The `size` for `memset()` is in bytes -- it doesn't know how big your array elements are.

Comment: Moving `usedNumbers` to become global causes it to be zeroed by default.  Your `memset()` only zeroes the first part (1/4 of it, with 4-byte `int`).

Comment: Btw, you could also use `int usedNumbers[256] = {0};` to initialise it and skip the `memset()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `usedNumbers` *inside* `main` is a local variable and these are not zero-initialized (i.e. they can contain garbage). Since you only use `memset(..., 256)`, only the first 256 **bytes** are zero-initialized, and the rest (e.g. half or three quarters of the array -- or more, depending on the size of `int`) is not.

The `usedNumbers` *outside* `main` is a global variable, however, and these are completely zero-initialized, even without `memset`. So there, you really have an empty array with no garbage in it, and that is why that works as expected.

So do:

```
    memset(usedNumbers, 0, sizeof(usedNumbers));
```

and both versions should produce the same, expected result.

Comment: Big thanks! I didn't noticed that, probably I have too much java in my head.

Comment: Can't comment on your head. Did you mean coffee or the language? ;-)

Comment: Language, I meant that I was programming in Java too much and I almost forgot how to program in C.